# Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type '(UIImagePickerController, [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : UIImage]) -> ()'

Tags: ios, xcode

I was working on my code when I got this error message at the part setProfilePicture : Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type '(UIImagePickerController, [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : UIImage]) -> ()'
Could somebody tell me what happened and how to fix it ?

```
//Selecting image from Gallery
@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]){

    //let profileImage =
    func profileImage(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                      didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : UIImage]){
        }
    setProfilePicture(imageView: self.imageSelector, imageToSet: profileImage)

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

// Displaying Profile Picture on the Image View
internal func setProfilePicture(imageView: UIImageView, imageToSet: UIImage){
    print("setProfilePicture called")
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 40
    imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.image = imageToSet
}
}
```

Comment: The function is (of course) non-optional so remove the exclamation mark. But I strongly doubt that passing the function as parameter is intended.

Comment: The problem is that when I remove the exclamation mark I get another error : Cannot convert value of type '(UIImagePickerController, [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : UIImage]) -> ()' to expected argument type 'UIImage'

Comment: I know, see the second part of the comment. it's unclear what you are going to accomplish.

Comment: I do that to then display the picture that way :

Comment: Please don't use the comments to add information. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52904026/edit) the question

Comment: It's done, I put what should happen after this line got executed :)

Comment: Do not delete a question that people have spent time and effort answering correctly. The right thing  is to accept a good answer, not delete it.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
func imagePickerController(
        _ picker: UIImagePickerController,
        didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]
        )
    {

        if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            setProfilePicture(imageView: self.imageSelector, imageToSet: image)
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think this way of writing the info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] no longer works in Swift 4.2 ( I get this error : Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Any]' with an index of type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey' )

Answer (score 0):

You second argument to the func setProfilePicture(imageView:imageToSet: is profileImage! which is the forced unwrapping of the function you have declared above as not being optional.

Comment: I don't understand how I am supposed to fix that ?

Comment: Remove the !, the ! is to force unwrap an optional, you don't have an optional type.

Comment: But the problem is that by removing the ! I get another error : Cannot convert value of type '(UIImagePickerController, [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : UIImage]) -> ()' to expected argument type 'UIImage'

Comment: Thats because you are try to pass a function as something that expects a UIImage. You need to pass it an UIImage. Look user9765456 example, though you you may not need the if let ... as? UIImage because you have declared you value type as UIImage not Any,.